# Magento checkout accordion not working

Tags: magento, prototype, accordion, checkout

I am desperate. I have been up all night trying to figure this out! I eliminated all of the no conflict errors but the checkout accordion still does not expand. See here http://test.animalnecessity.com/checkout/onepage/. Add something to cart> checkout> select pet owner and you will see what I'm saying. Desperate please help!

Answer (score 1):

When you click on 'I am a Pet Owner' it show the regular one page checkout but this div is still not visible

```
<div id="checkout-step-login" class="step a-item" style="display:none;">
```

Try using this to fix it using JS

```
 jQuery('#iampetowner').click(function() { 
     jQuery('#checkoutSteps').slideDown(); 
     jQuery('#petdvm').slideUp(); jQuery('#newpass').slideUp();
     jQuery('#checkout-step-login').show(); 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to solve it (until you have a chance to troubleshoot this properly), is to do the following:

- add the following code to your template (it should be placed in a document.ready function)

`jQuery('#checkout-step-login').show();`

P.S. there are errors on your register page see [here](http://test.animalnecessity.com/customer/account/create/)